# Dart/Flutter: horizontally scrollable week view - how to display particular items from the ListView?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, calendar, widget

I've been trying to make horizontal weekly calendar without using third party packages. I've created a horizontally scrollable Listview, containing three weeks : previous, current and next. Obviously, Listview displays from the first item in the list, which is the first day of the previuos week. Is there any way to control the items displayed and to display the current week with previous and next weeks being accessed through horizontal scrolling?

Here is the code for the ListView.builder:

```
Container(
          height: 60,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              itemCount: threeWeeks2.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var date = DateFormat('d').format(threeWeeks2[index]);
                return DayCardBig(date);
              }
              ),
        ),
```

Also, I can't keep but wondering whether the logic behind this implementation of week view is sound. I tried a more complex widget using carousel slider and pageview, but it just got messy. Is there any other widget that I'm not familiar with that I could use for a scrollable week view ?

Comment: Maybe the dismissible widget? If you want full control you can write your own widget Dismissible + AnimatedSwitcher